# How to use AMD with angular-cli?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli, amd

I am trying to move my existing angular 2 project to angular-cli. My current scaffolding uses Webpack and I use AMD quite a lot to load certain js files only inside some components asynchronous. 
Ex :

```
require(['json-fn'], (JSONfn) => {
        srvc.JSONfn = JSONfn;
    });
```

the new angular-cli scaffolding gives the following error :

```
 Cannot find name 'require'.
```

and webpack compilation fails. What do I do?

Comment: `declare let require: any`

Comment: doesn't do any good :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

angular-cli uses webpack 2 to build projects, which supports AMD, however you need to use the `import` statement:

```
import * as jsonFn from 'json-fn';

// ..

ngOnInit() {
    // use it normally here
    jsonFn.parse();
}
```

Comment: Let me try this and get back immediately

Comment: Seems to work fine. Thanks. But is it really AMD or is jsonFn getting bundled in the main js only?

Comment: It's pretty different, just the TS approach of loading dependencies.